# Copying db in SQL Server 2008 R2 issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I've made a copy of a database in SQL Server R2 for dev purposes using the wizzard.  That part worked fine.  In my code, I've changed the connection string in web.config to point to the new db:

```
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=\dev;Initial Catalog=live_DEV;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<!--<add name="liveConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=\dev;Initial Catalog=live;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
```

I've changed the actual names of the servers etc. for security reasons but the format is the same.  As you can see, I've commented out the old db and changed to a copy.

I'm using VS2010 and have changed all references from the old connection to my dev copy:

```
using (SqlConnection connIncident_TrackerDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=\dev;Initial Catalog=live_DEV;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
```

I've checked the stored procedures in my dev copy which all have [USE live_DEV] as a header.  I've cleaned and rebuild the code.  I've restarted my ASP.NET Development Server and ran it.

When I do and check the databases, it's updating both live and dev copies.  What am I missing?

thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you missed some place in the code where the connection string has been hard coded. I suggest 2 things

First change your privileges to disallow access to production.  This will keep you from accidentally updating production with test code.  And it will cause your app to break wherever production is getting updated (This might lead you to the cause of the problem).

Second remove all hard coded connection strings from the app and only use the connection string in the web.config